# NSPredicate - compare with a rounded int

Tags: sorting, nsarray, nspredicate

I am currently using the following NSPredicate to sort an array I have:

```
        [filteredResults filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"note.intValue >= %ld", rating]];
```

Basically, the `note` element goes from 1 to 5, but it's not an int, it's a float that can be 4.5, or 4.75, or 4.2. The `rating` object, on the other hand, is an int: it's either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. What I would like to achieve is that if `note` is 4.75, it should be kept in the sorting if `rating` is 5.
In other words, I would like to compare `rating` to `note`, but rounded to the closest half.

Is there any way to achieve this while keeping the extremely simple and useful NSPredicate syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the floating point value is contained in the corresponding 
interval:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"note >= %f AND note < %f",
     (double)rating - 0.5, (double)rating + 0.5]
```

Comment: Or, since the original predicate was just checking `>=`, just use `@"note >= %f", (double)rating - 0.25`. (0.25 because he wants rounding to the nearest half, not rounding to the nearest int.)